# Bibliography style (author, year) without BibTeX (without \bibliography{} but with \begin{thebibliography} and \bibitem)

Tags: citing, bibliographystyle

LaTeX can create citations in [number] format. However, I would need the format (author, year). And with the same cross-reference function as in the original numeric format. At the same time, I would like to use only the \begin{thebibliography} command, i.e. not use BibTeX and some other .bib file, but just write the literature manually via \bibitem. Is that possible?

*Thanks for the answers and sorry if the question is already answered somewhere, I didn't find it.*

Comment: yes, natbib can also handle manual bibliographies, you only need to use the optional argument of \bibitem correctly. See the natbib documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: Yes.

Longer answer: Absolutely.

Even longer answer: Give the following minimalist document a try. Observe the use of the optional argument of `\bibitem` to store the citation call-out string and publication year. Compile the document twice to generate the citation call-outs correctly.

You will, of course, still be in charge of *everything* related to bibliography: The ordering of the bib entries, the formatting of the bib entries, etc., etc.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}

\begin{document}
\citet{jms:3001}, \citep{abcd:2005}

\begin{thebibliography}{2}

% Important: leave no space between citation callout 
% string and (year) in the optional argument.
\bibitem[Andersen et~al.(2005)]{abcd:2005} Andersen, Torben G., 
   Tim Bollerslev, Peter Christoffersen, and Francis X. Diebold 
   (2005), ``Volatility Forecasting,'' Manuscript.

\bibitem[Jones et~al.(3001)]{jms:3001} Jones, Hillary, Maria 
   Miller, and Sandra Smith, ``Thoughts,'' \emph{Circularity 
   Today}, 3(2) 456--789.
    
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```